# Python dotenv not reading variables completely

Tags: python, environment-variables

This is file test.py

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

print(os.environ.get('DB_HOST'))
```

This is env file

```
DB_HOST="mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@playground.xxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

but the output is just

```
mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@playground.xxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites
```

everytime I reinstall python-dotenv, python-dotenv read the variable completely. but then python-dotenv read the variable incomplete.

how to solve this ?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on my end. The code seems to be working as expected. Did you run the code on terminal or through other software like vscode or IDLE? So the issue is that `load_dotenv` only loads the right value for the first time and afterwards when running again it doesn't work? I think it could be that the env variable value Is manipulated anywhere in the code

Comment: I don't speak Javascript but the regex in https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js looks like it really doesn't want equals signs in the values.

Comment: @taxevader. yeah dotenv only loads the right value for the first time

Comment: @taxevader, what do you mean about "the env variable value Is manipulated anywhere in the code" ? can you explain it more ?